# VPS ubuntu ip connect and ip local are difference

Tags: ip, vps

I use putty to connect to VPS ubuntu, with IP: 23.XX.XX.45.
But when I show IP on VPS : "hostname -I " IP: 10.x.x.8

I do not know , Why they are difference.

link screen
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQqND.jpg

Comment: That is because you are connecting to the Public IP of 23.x.x.45 and not the Private IP which is what the 10.x.x.8 IP is.

Comment: Thank Terrance
so when I access tomcat from other PC, can I access by URL : http://23.XX.XX.45:8080/

Comment: and the Router  binding IP address 23.XX.XX.45. to  10.x.x.8 ? is that true ?

Comment: If you run `ip addr` from within your VPS it will show you all your associated IPs to that VPS.  Chances are the 23.x.x.45 might be a forwarded IP to the internal VPS IP of 10.0.0.8.

Comment: Thank Terrance, now I learning about forwarded IP